# Как выключить case sensetive в postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

У меня такая проблема, мне нужно отключить в postgresql case sensetive (чувствительность к регистру) - погуглив я ответа не нашел, есть небольшое уточнение, мне нужно именно в posgresql выключить без указаний в запросах to lower и тп.

Comment: Он по умолчанию такой же, нет?

Comment: К сожалению нет. К примеру запрос SELECT * FROM tests."users"; не выполняет. А запрос SELECT * FROM tests."Users"; успешно проходит.

Comment: Ну так уточнили бы где именно оно надо. Тут, как минимум это делать не корректно, так как наименование таблиц и полей обычно (как правило) идёт всегда в нижнем регистре.

Comment: тоесть Вы предлагает пересоздать таблицу с использованием только нижнего регистра?

Comment: Советую почитать лучшие практики по SQL conventions

Comment: Да спасибо всем, помогло пересоздание таблиц, сделал их названия нижним регистром и проблем не возникает больше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> К примеру запрос SELECT * FROM tests."users"; не выполняет. А запрос
>   SELECT * FROM tests."Users"; успешно проходит.

Вы сами явным образом попросили case sensitive название таблицы тем что [заключили имя таблицы в кавычки](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html).

> Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas unquoted
>   names are always folded to lower case. For example, the identifiers
>   FOO, foo, and "foo" are considered the same by PostgreSQL, but "Foo"
>   and "FOO" are different from these three and each other.

Названия объектов в кавычках всегда регистрозависимы. Названия без использования кавычек приводятся парсером к нижнему регистру - потому обычно объекты в postgresql именуются в нижнем регистре с использованием подчёркивания.